# Okta + ASPX WEBFORMS + EMBEDDED WIDGET : 401 error for token

Tags: asp.net, webforms, okta, okta-signin-widget

I am using a self hosted widget in aspx page which was created in classic engine. Since moved into the identity engine ,I have added : useInteractionCodeFlow: true, (as mentioned in Okta documentation)
after making these changes , the login is not working properly.

Initial approach : throws 401 error while trying to get the token

```
signIn.renderEl({
el: ‘#widget-container’
}, function success(res) {
if (res.status === ‘SUCCESS’) {
debugger;
console.log(‘Do something with this sessionToken’, res.session.token);
} else {
}
```

Hence instead of initial approach for render , made changes like:

```
signIn.showSignInAndRedirect()
.catch(err => {
console.log('Error happen in showSignInAndRedirect: ', err);
});
```

in this approach its getting redirected but Token is not generated (Token is required for OWIN challenge)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code for the okta widget. This works for me, hope this helps you.

```
public class StartupOkta
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LoginOkta"),
            });
            app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
                LoginMode=LoginMode.SelfHosted
            });
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "preferred_username";
        }
    }
```

code in your controller :-

```
if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
                properties.Dictionary.Add("sessionToken", form.Get("sessionToken"));
                properties.RedirectUri = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"]);

                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties,
                    OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationType);

                return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
```